# Как разделить объекты на категории в массиве для передачи данных?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я бы хотел разделить обьекты по категориям например чтобы было так: `[obj1: {...}, obj2: {...}]` - ну или как то так, задача у меня стоит - передать на backend данные с двух категорий. Можно ли как то разделить?

```
$('.app-btn-green').on('click', function() {
        var elements = [];
        $('.droppable-list-1 .drop-block__list-item').each(function() {
            elements.push({
                eventName: $(this).attr("data-event-name"),
                sort: $(this).attr("data-sort"),
                class: $(this).attr("class"),
                icon: $(this).find(".drop-block__icon use").attr("xlink:href")
            });
        });
        $('.droppable-list-2 .drop-block__list-item').each(function() {
            elements.push({
                eventName: $(this).attr("data-account-name"),
                sort: $(this).attr("data-sort"),
                class: $(this).attr("class"),
                icon: $(this).find(".drop-block__icon use").attr("xlink:href")
            });
        });
        elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
        console.log(elements);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так:

```
$('.app-btn-green').on('click', function() {
    var class1 = [], 
        class2 = [];
    $('.droppable-list-1 .drop-block__list-item').each(function() {
        class1.push({
            eventName: $(this).attr("data-event-name"),
            sort: $(this).attr("data-sort"),
            class: $(this).attr("class"),
            icon: $(this).find(".drop-block__icon use").attr("xlink:href")
        });
    });
    $('.droppable-list-2 .drop-block__list-item').each(function() {
        class2.push({
            eventName: $(this).attr("data-account-name"),
            sort: $(this).attr("data-sort"),
            class: $(this).attr("class"),
            icon: $(this).find(".drop-block__icon use").attr("xlink:href")
        });
    });
    elements = {
        class1: class1,
        class2: class2
    };
    elements = JSON.stringify(elements)
    console.log(elements);
});
```

Comment: возможно я не правильно вас понял

Comment: правильно вы поняли, спасибо